# Best Practice to Lazy Load Huge Data into a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/cL8ej4fa/2/) that make an AJAX to get this [Data](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1egsx) to render a table. My goal is load **only** 10 rows during the first initial page load.

#### HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true,
    "processing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,

    ajax: {
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1egsx',
      dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    columns: [
      { data: 'account_id' },
      { data: 'name' },
      { data: 'email' }
    ],
    "deferRender": true,
    "deferLoading": 10,

  } );

});
```

I've been trying to use datatables JavaScript plug-in, but it doesn't seem to work.

Are there any other scripts/plug-ins/frameworks I should look into?

Comment: Using a generator function to provide data in 10 row chunks at each request (`iterator.next()`) could be one way

Comment: why not use pagination on the server side?

Comment: generator function, what logics goes in there ? I'm not clear what you were saying at the moment.

Comment: @Gogol :  Pagination on server side, is it a best practice ? I can look into that. I current use datatables JS plug-in right now, and it turn all my accounts into a nicely pagination as well, and it takes awhile to load, so do you think the server side pagination will give me a different result than client side pagination ?

Comment: Ofcourse! This way you do not hurt your db in every call.. just use limit and offset.

Comment: @Gogol : Since I don't do direct query to my database, I call an API, do you think it will work with `$accounts = Session::get('accounts')->paginate(10);`, I kept getting `Call to a member function paginate() on array` .....

Comment: In addition to pagination, I suggest you look into virtual scrolling. That means, you keep the data in the background and only render the part of the data into the DOM that's visible to the user. Here's a demo of w2ui's virtual scrolling on 1 million records: http://w2ui.com/web/blog/7/JavaScript-Grid-with-One-Million-Records (btw, w2ui also supports server side lazy-loading). Disclaimer: I'm a w2ui contributor.

Comment: i've worked with 10k rows of date and pagination on server side is the best option.

Comment: i dont know if you would want to download 10k+ rows if the user only scrolls through 50...upvote for server side pagination

Comment: @ihue you should implement pagination in the api itself..

Comment: @Gogol : pagination in the api itself ? Since I am not the Back End guy, what should I tell him in order to update his API results ?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval : Do you use Laravel ? Do you mind answer your suggestion ? I would love to see how you do that ?

Comment: @ihue yes just tell him you need pagination for that particular api method because your app cannot handle so much data at once. Two variables, e.g. per_page, and offset should do it.

Comment: @Gogol : Okay, thanks for your help on this. What is `per_page, and offset ` I don't have the clear image for that.

Comment: You will send per_page and offset to the api. per_page being the number of result you want per page and offset being the offset of the result.. e.g. per_page 10, offset 0 should pull up the first 10 results. per_page 10 and offset 50 should pull up 51th to 60th records. This is how the api will know which record to return.

Comment: @Gogol : Thank-you very much for your elaborate.

Comment: Sorry @ihue i use Spring, but i'm sure that Laravel must have a library for pagination on server side, like Spring